# "Flutter InAppWebView Not Handling Blob URLs for PDF Download Correctly"

Tags: flutter, dart, blob

I'm working on a Flutter project where I'm using the flutter_inappwebview package to display a web view. My goal is to enable users to download PDF files, which may be linked via blob URLs. However, I'm encountering issues with the download functionality, specifically when dealing with blob URLs.
Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


import 'package:yeniweb/core/pdf_ac.dart';

class WebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  WebViewScreen({required this.url});

  @override
  _WebViewScreenState createState() => _WebViewScreenState();
}



class _WebViewScreenState extends State<WebViewScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> _scaffoldKey =
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  Dio dio = Dio();
  double downloadProgress = 0.0;
  bool isLoading = true;
  bool showSnackBar = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
        handlerName: 'base64String',
        callback: (args) async {
          String base64String = args[0];
          final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          final filePath = p.join(dir.path, 'downloaded_file.pdf'); // Change extension as needed
          decodeBase64AndWriteToFile(base64String, filePath);
          openPDF(filePath);
        }
    );


  }
  void decodeBase64AndWriteToFile(String base64String, String filePath) {
    final bytes = base64.decode(base64String.split(',').last);
    File(filePath).writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
    // Continue with your logic (e.g., opening the file)
  }




  Future<void> startDownload(String url) async {
    try {
      if (url.isEmpty || !Uri.parse(url).isAbsolute) {
        throw 'Invalid URL';
      }

      final fileName = p.basename(url);
      final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final filePath = p.join(dir.path, fileName);

      if (!url.startsWith('blob:')) {
        await dio.download(url, filePath, onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
          setState(() {
            downloadProgress = received / total;
          });
        });
        openPDF(filePath);
      } else {
        print("Blob URL detected, handling separately...");
        // Blob URL handling logic
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Download error: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> handleBlobUrl(String blobUrl) async {
    try {
      // JavaScript içinde blob URL'yi base64 string'e dönüştüren fonksiyonu çağırın
      print('$blobUrl');
      await webViewController?.evaluateJavascript(source: """
      (function() {
        fetch('$blobUrl')
          .then(response => response.blob())
          .then(blob => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
              // Flutter'a base64 string'ini gönderin
              window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('base64String', reader.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Blob conversion error:', error));
      })();
    """);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error handling blob URL: $e');
    }
  }





  void showDownloadDialog(String url) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        startDownload(url);
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('indiriliyor...'),
          content: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return LinearProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress);
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(

              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },   child: Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void openPDF(String filePath) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => PDFViewPage(filePath: filePath),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('SnackBar içeriği'),
      ));
    });
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text("Web View",),

      ),

        body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          InAppWebView(
            onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = true;
              });
            },
            onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
            initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.url)),
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                javaScriptEnabled: true,
                useOnDownloadStart: true,
              ),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              webViewController = controller;

              // JavaScript to handle blob URLs
              webViewController?.evaluateJavascript(source: """
    document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('downloadBlob', link.href);
    });
  """);
              controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            function convertBlobToBase64(blobUrl, callback) {
              fetch(blobUrl)
                .then(response => response.blob())
                .then(blob => {
                  const reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onloadend = () => callback(reader.result);
                  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Blob conversion error:', error));
            }
          """);


              // Set up the JavaScript handler for 'downloadBlob'
              webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                  handlerName: 'downloadBlob',
                  callback: (args) {
                    // args[0] is the blob URL
                    handleBlobUrl(args[0]);
                  }
              );

              // Set up the JavaScript handler for 'base64String'
              webViewController?.addJavaScriptHandler(
                  handlerName: 'base64String',
                  callback: (args) {
                    // args[0] is the base64 string
                    // handle the base64 string here
                  }
              );
            },

            onDownloadStartRequest:  (controller, request) async {
      final url = request.url.toString();
      if (url.startsWith('blob:')) {
        // Handle blob URL differently
        print("blob algılandı");
        handleBlobUrl(url);
      } else {
        // Handle other URLs with the existing method
        showDownloadDialog(url);
        print("blob algılanmadı "
            "");
      }
    },

          ),
          isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : SizedBox.shrink(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to download PDF files linked via blob URLs. The expected behavior is for the app to fetch the blob URL, convert it to a base64 string, and then download the file. Instead, what I'm observing is [describe the observed behavior, e.g., nothing happens, an error occurs, etc.].

Some specific questions I have are:

Is there a better way to handle blob URLs for file downloads in Flutter's WebView?
Are there any specific settings or configurations in the InAppWebView that I might be missing for this to work?
Has anyone successfully implemented PDF downloading from blob URLs in Flutter and can offer some guidance?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I think you should try to handle downloads on the mobile side instead of the web.

I encountered a similar issue when trying to `screenshot` webview content and `send` it as base64 to mobile.

The webview is not responding because the library used to capture content is very slow in the webview. Everything works fine if I only `send` base64 data.

You can debug the webview to check the download function via `chrome://inspect` for android and `safari develop` for iOS device

Hope this helps!